# SQL Server 2008 Case Statement with SET operation

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, set, case

I am using Sql server 2008

I am looking for a idle statement like this in T-SQL

```
SELECT CASE @H_CNT 
 WHEN 2 THEN 
 @H_VAR_1 = @H_VALUE_1
 WHEN 3 THEN
 @H_VAR_2 = @H_VALUE_2
END
```

But the above statement is not accepted and shows error .

What is the issue here

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** - it can return a value (literal or SQL variables), but it **CANNOT** execute a code block

Comment: @user3481294 Please edit the post to include the error message. That will give context to the issue and allow others to focus their answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @H_VAR_1 = CASE WHEN @H_CNT = 2 THEN @H_VALUE_1 ELSE @H_VAR_1 END,
       @H_VAR_2 = CASE WHEN @H_CNT = 3 THEN @H_VALUE_2 ELSE @H_VAR_2 END
```

Comment: ,it works thanks.but your answers won't suit me in my situation Basically i have a if statement which is executed once for every record.
i have 50 million records so these if gets executed for ecery record,so probably if i use case it will make the code faster

Comment: You probably just need to add a where condition. But hard to tell without any tables, example data or expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can't assign within a `CASE` statement.  You can assign from the *results of* a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT @H_VAR_1 = CASE @H_CNT WHEN 2 THEN @H_VALUE_1 ELSE @H_VAR_1 END,  
       @H_VAR_2 = CASE @H_CNT WHEN 3 THEN @H_VALUE_2 ELSE @H_VAR_2 END
```

Comment: great,thats what i like to know Roryap